# How many times can I change my Facebook name?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I must have a facebook for business reasons, but I’m not comfortable using my real name or email there due to privacy issues. A such, I frequently change my “name” to various pop culture references. How many times am I allow to do this before banned?

Comment: And you're not using a page for your business because...?

Comment: @Eddie. I only have a facebook account because the do not allow to view anthing by unregister users.

Answer (score 1):

you wont get banned for changing your username, they will just stop letting you change the name after a few changes. so you will be stuck with whichever was the last change you made.

Comment: Is there any reference to back this up?

Comment: yes: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=can+no+longer+change+facebook+name&aq=f&oq=can+no+longer+change+facebook+name&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65l3j0.4499&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8